# Is it possible to create a generic method that take a method group as an argument

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to create a method that would allow a "method group" to be passed in. Basically this is for testing where I want to make sure that a method was called. FakeItEasy already allows for the following code

```
public static IAnyCallConfigurationWithReturnTypeSpecified<ReturnType> ReturnForMethod<SUT, ReturnType>(
          this Fake<SUT> fake,
           string methodName, ReturnType returnObj)
      {
          var call = fake.AnyCall().WithReturnType<ReturnType>().Where(s => s.Method.Name == methodName);

          call.Returns(returnObj);
          return call;
      }

//Called using 
new Fake<IDummyFactory>().ReturnForMethod(nameof(IDummyFactory.Create), testStr);
```

For cleaner code I'd prefer to write something like

```
public static IAnyCallConfigurationWithReturnTypeSpecified<ReturnType> ReturnForMethodF<SUT ,ReturnType>(
            this Fake<SUT> fake,
            MethodGroup method, ReturnType returnObj)
```

Basically the same way nameof works. Using a function so I would want the method called as follows

```
new Fake<IDummyFactory>().ReturnForMethod(s=> s.Create, testStr); --NoInvoke as just want method group
```

Comment: Would a parameter of type `Action` which you initialise at the call-site using a lambda work for you? (Simimlar to how many Linq methods work.)

Comment: Nope. This is not an Action. Its basically a weird type of "method group" but that seems to be some internal type and not something devs have access too. Can't really find any documention on it either

Comment: Basically, I know I can't use genrics here (unless I specify types) because the compiler won't know which method to use (if it was overloaded). In my case I don't really care about the specifics I really just want a neat way of saying nameof. Thought it would be cool if I could say method group with a return type of X

Comment: Method groups are a compile time concept - they have no runtime representation. E.g. if you use reflection and ask a type for it's methods of a particular name, you get back an enumerable of MethodInfos, not this mythical MethodGroup that you're looking for.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so basically you're saying not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Method group" is a concept that exists only in the language's syntax, there is no runtime type that corresponds to a method group.

Before I answer the question, you can just do this at callsite:

```cs
new Fake<IDummyFactory>().ReturnForMethod(nameof(s.Create), testStr);
```

I don't see any reason `s => s.Create` would be better or more readable than `nameof(s.Create)`.

Now for the fun part. Method groups are convertible to compatible delegate types [as governed by an impossibly complicated set of magic rules](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/spec/conversions.md#method-group-conversions).

So we would be looking for a method with a signature of:

```cs
public static IAnyCallConfigurationWithReturnTypeSpecified<TReturnType> ReturnForMethod<TSUT, TDelegate, TReturnType>(
    this Fake<TSUT> fake,
    Expression<Func<TSUT, TDelegate>> methodGroupExpression,
    TReturnType returnObject) where TSUT : class 
                              where TDelegate : Delegate
```

We're working with `Expression`s, so we will have to create an `ExpressionVisitor` that traverses the `Expression` tree and looks for method calls on the appropriate type. For simplicity we are going to assume that you are always calling the method with just a single `x => x.Foo` expression. Assuming we have a visitor class that does this, the body of our method is straightforward:

```cs
public static IAnyCallConfigurationWithReturnTypeSpecified<TReturnType> ReturnForMethod<TSUT, TDelegate, TReturnType>(
    this Fake<TSUT> fake,
    Expression<Func<TSUT, TDelegate>> methodGroupExpression,
    TReturnType returnObject) where TSUT : class 
                                where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    var visitor = new ExtractMethodNameExpressionVisitor<TSUT>();
    var methodName = visitor.ExtractMethodName(methodGroupExpression);

    if (methodName is null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    var call = fake.AnyCall().WithReturnType<TReturnType>().Where(s => s.Method.Name == methodName);

    call.Returns(returnObject);
    return call;
}
```

The expression `s => s.Create` is enriched with some magical compiler generated code during compilation, which converts it to the appropriate delegate type. But the method group itself is nested somewhere in it as a `ConstantExpression` of type `MethodInfo`. Our visitor class will traverse the tree, find such an expression and save its name.

```
class ExtractMethodNameExpressionVisitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private string? _methodName;

    public string? ExtractMethodName(Expression expression)
    {
        _methodName = null;

        this.Visit(expression);
        return _methodName;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == typeof(MethodInfo) && 
            node.Value is MethodInfo methodInfo &&
            methodInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(T))
        {
            _methodName = methodInfo.Name;
        }

        return base.VisitConstant(node);
    }
}
```

And now we can test this:

```
var fake = new Fake<IDummyFactory>();

fake.ReturnForMethod(s => s.Create, "testStr");

var result = fake.FakedObject.Create();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The unfortunate part is that this doesn't work. As of C#9 at least, delegate types are kind of a second-class citizen in the language, and generic type inference for them does not work. So the above `ReturnForMethod` call does not compile, because the compiler cannot infer that a function returning `string` and taking no arguments is actually `Func<string>`. So the callsite must look like this:

```cs
fake.ReturnForMethod<IDummyFactory, Func<string>, string>(s => s.Create, "testStr");
```

which makes this solution much less appealing. The good news is that, if I understand the proposals correctly, in C#10 (or maybe C#11 if the feature misses C#10's release window) this would work without the explicit type signature.

You can find the full working demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/We0Wjt).

Comment: You had me at "Now for the fun part" :D

Comment: Haha, I actually did the fun part and also got stymied on the inference of the compiler. I have already implemented with name of, my issue with it is that its not type bound.  This was super informative though. Thank You!